# Change Flash source by Python

Tags: python, flash

I have flash with big image library inside, is there way to manipulate this content by python?

Comment: That's *way* too few information to enable people to help you.

Comment: please try to give some more details. manipulate in what way?

Answer (score 0):

Python Flash Tools intended to be a level up from the Ming SWF library and a step down from a Flash GUI see http://pyswftools.sourceforge.net/